# Erro quando coloca o SUM

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

Estou tentando implementar o `SUM` dentro dessas linhas de código para fazer a soma das duas colunas `Litro` e `TotalGasto`

Código:

```
var teste = consulta.Where(i => i.DtAbastecido >= dataInicio &&
                                i.DtAbastecido <= dataFinal)
                    .Sum(x =>x.Litro)
                    .GroupBy(x => new { x.NumCarro.NCarro })
                    .Select(x => x.First())
                    .OrderBy(x => x.NumCarro.NCarro);
```

Mas estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> 'int' does not contain a definition for 'GroupBy' and no extension method 'GroupBy' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using reference or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É porque a query não faz sentido, primeiro você está fazendo a soma e depois tentando agrupar.

Tenha em mente, primeiramente, que o `Sum` retorna um **número inteiro**. Logo, não faz sentido tentar aplicar um `GroupBy` depois de usar o método `Sum`.

Provavelmente você queria fazer assim:

```
var teste = consulta.Where(i => i.DtAbastecido >= dataInicio &&
                                i.DtAbastecido <= dataFinal)
                    .GroupBy(x => new { x.NumCarro.NCarro })
                    .Select(x => x.First())
                    .Sum(x =>x.Litro);
```